# Google doesnt work on https but it work on http

Tags: php, http, curl, https, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the api of google to send push notificacion, the issue is that if I use "http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" it works perfect but if I use 
"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" (with S on http) It doesnt work and the curl stop.

Anyone knows why?

```
$headers = array('Authorization:key=' . $apiKey);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
"http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
if ($headers)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: `It doesnt work and the curl stop.` 1/ How doesn't it work? What is the problem/error? 2/ How does CURL stop?

Comment: echo "this is visible";
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   echo "this is not visible";

when i use the https, it only show "this is visible", nothing more, when i use the http, it show both text

Comment: Either turn on error reporting or look in the error logs to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get response in both cases :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);

function o($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization:key=123']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [1,2,3]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

var_dump( o("http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send") );
var_dump( o("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send") );
```

So you probably have error somewhere.

Comment: do you have any errors? write `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);` on the begining of the file, and report to us if you have any errors.

Comment: the only error i get is that the variables are empty, but still only 1 response

Comment: If you save my code in `some.php` file and run it, you still get errors?

Comment: @D4rWiNS : What was the problem?

Comment: We still dont know if i use the script at my home it works but if i use it from the work it doesnt work so it's seems to be something in the config of the server i told it to my boss and he sent a ticket to our server manager